# Ordem de operações no R

Tags: r

Como funciona a ordem das operações no R? E como posso alterá-las?

Por exemplo, quando faço `1 + 2^2` no `R`, ele sabe que primeiro é necessário avaliar o `2^2` para depois somar o resultado com o `1`.

Neste caso, claro que não faz sentido querer alterar esta ordem. Mas, o que eu gostaria de fazer é algo como o inverso do operador `%>%` do `dplyr`que funcione da seguinte forma:

```
exp %<% 1 + 1
# 7.389056 = exp(2)
```

Assim, seria necessário que o `1+1`fosse avaliado antes do `%<%`, será que isso é possível?

Eu tentei isso:

```
"%<%" <- function(l,r) return(l(r))
exp %<% 1 + 1
# 3.718282
```

Mas isso é a mesma coisa que:

```
exp(1) + 1
# 3.718282
```

Comment: Você não quer fazer `exp %<% (1+1)`, certo?

Comment: exato, não queria usar os parenteses

Comment: Não sei se tem como fazer isso, até porque seria uma confusão se isso fosse algo personalizável, dificultando bastante o entendimento/leitura de códigos, além de fazer com que outros parassem de funcionar como esperado.

Comment: concordo, que pode gerar confusão. Mas existem outras funções que fazem esse tipo de coisa... Por exemplo o operador `<-`, quando faço `x <- 1 + 1`, `1 + 1` é calculado antes de `<-` ser de fato usado.

Comment: Daniel, o que você disse tem a ver com ?Syntax (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), que mostra a precedência de todos os operadores. Note que `%any%` é um deles. Ou seja, ao definir um operador `%<%` ele tem precedência menor que `+`, mas maior que `*` (note que no seu exemplo `exp %<% 2 * 2` dá o resultado que você queria). O problema (problemão) é tentar mudar a precedência da sua função. Eu acho que se for possível essa tarefa é difícil (vai precisar definir classes), mas posso estar errado. Veja ?groupGeneric e ?S4groupGeneric

Comment: Vixe, falei besteira. Também não funciona com `*`, pois a precedência de `%any%` é maior. Mas funciona com `:`, por exemplo. `exp %<% 1:10` resulta num vetor com os resultados. Ou então  `exp %<% 2^2`, que também dá o que você queria.

Comment: @JulioTrecenti é isso aí, como `+` (binário) tem precedência a `<-`, então em `x <- 1 + 1` a soma é feita antes de atribuir. No caso, o operador do Daniel `%<%` é um operador especial que tem precedência a `+` (binário), então o `%<%` será executado primeiro, a não ser que se coloquem parênteses. Acho que você deveria colocar isso como resposta.

Comment: Daniel, +1 boa pergunta. Não acho que dê para alterar a precedência de um operador binário, pelas razões que @Rcoster elencou.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli eu não coloquei como resposta pois não tenho uma solução nem tenho como provar que é impossível (ou extremamente difícil) de fazer essa mudança de precedência, então não é bem uma resposta. Faz sentido? Ainda não sei usar direito o SO.

Comment: @JulioTrecenti Sim, sem problemas, o Daniel perguntou duas coisas `"Como funciona a ordem das operações no R? E como posso alterá-las?"` você pode explicar a ordem das operações, então estará respondendo a uma parte da pergunta, e quanto a segunda parte não tem problema falar que não sabe.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli +1 pela dica. Me convenceu, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou reescrever parte dos meus comentários como resposta à pergunta

> Como funciona a ordem das operações no R?

@DanielFalbel, o que você disse tem a ver com o conceito de "precedência" e está definido em [?Syntax](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), que mostra a precedência de todos os operadores do R. Abaixo copio o texto do help do R, mostrando a hierarquia dos operadores (o primeiro é o que tem maior precedência):

```
:: :::  access variables in a namespace
$ @ component / slot extraction
[ [[    indexing
^   exponentiation (right to left)
- + unary minus and plus
:   sequence operator
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%)
* / multiply, divide
+ - (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
!   negation
& &&    and
| ||    or
~   as in formulae
-> ->>  rightwards assignment
<- <<-  assignment (right to left)
=   assignment (right to left)
?   help (unary and binary)
```

Note que `%any%` (ou seja, qualquer operador definido com `% %`) é um deles. Ou seja, ao definir um operador `%<%` ele tem precedência maior que `+`, mas menor que `^` (note que no seu exemplo `exp %<% 2 ^ 2` dá o resultado que você queria).

O problema (problemão) é tentar mudar a precedência da sua função. Uma solução trivial seria utilizar parênteses,

```
exp %<% (1+1)
```

mas pelo que disse você queria evitá-los.

Dando uma olhada nas definições dos operadores, eu acho que se for possível essa tarefa pode ser bastante difícil (precisará provavelmente definir classes que trabalhem ao lado de operadores primitivos explicitamente), mas posso estar errado. Veja [?groupGeneric](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/groupGeneric.html) e [?S4groupGeneric](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/S4groupGeneric.html) para alguns detalhes sobre como os operadores primitivos são implementados.

Comment: "ao definir um operador %<% ele tem precedência menor que +, mas maior que ^ " seria o contrário, o %<% tem precedência maior que + (binário, o de soma) e menor que ^.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli corrigido.

Comment: muito legal Julio! realmente parece ser complicado tentar mudar essa ordem... talvez seja possível fazer alguma gambiarra usando non-standard evaluation e `sys.call`